Which path minimizes travel time for an object moving along a downward parabolic trajectory without friction?
I am studying a physics problem where an object moves from one point to another under frictionless conditions. The trajectory of the object is shaped like a downward parabola, but the exact curvature can vary. All possible paths have the same horizontal displacement (x).

Is there a general mathematical or physical method (e.g., variational principles or the principle of least action) that can determine the optimal downward parabolic path in this scenario?
Given that the horizontal displacement is fixed and the motion is frictionless, how can I determine the parabola that minimizes the travel time?
What I’ve tried:
•   I attempted to use the mean value theorem to analyze the velocity changes along different paths, but I couldn’t directly identify the path with the shortest time.
•   I explored variational methods and considered whether the problem relates to the brachistochrone curve, but I’m not sure if this applies to downward parabolic trajectories.

As shown in the diagram, the object starts at an initial velocity v on the left and follows a downward parabolic path to reach the other side. My question is: which specific parabolic shape minimizes the time required for the object to travel from one side to the other?


You should at least show examples of your working, specifically the second one. Have you done a calculus of variations problem ever before?

It's important to say that conditions are incomplete. You need to specify force acting on a projectile or specific projectile acceleration $a(t)$, since it can't be a gravity acceleration $g$ because it would be upwards and all possible trajectories would have different horizontal displacement depending on angle $\theta$ with horizon. So without some sort of custom force specification it's impossible to minimize path time since it can be multiple.

Does it have to be a parabola? or any shape? If any shape is okay, then the shape is a cycloid .

Do you mean it starts with a speed $v$?

@DutaKartvelishvili Thanks for your comment, it has to be a parabola.

@ProfRob Thanks for your comment, sorry, I just realize the situation will be different if the initial speed is not 0, my first idea is that the initial speed is 0 and the object rolls down because of gravity. Sorry for misleading!

No, I mean you say you know the initial velocity, which is a vector. If you know this, then surely the path is already defined?

Without gravitation, we can say that the shortest time between two points is the straight line path,(infinitely squashed parabola). With gravitation  we can setup the variational problem as the following
$$t= \int dt = \int \frac{ds}{|v|} = \int \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx}{|v|}$$
From conservation of energy
$$\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = 1/2mv_0^2 - mgy$$
$$|v|= \sqrt{v_0^2 -2gy}$$
If we want to constrain the problem for parabola solutions we know that $y=ax^2 + bx +c$ with the condition that $y=0,x=0$ and $y=0 , x=l$
$C=0, 0= al^2+bl , al+b = 0 ,b= -al$
$Y= ax^2 -alx$
Now we get that
$y'= 2ax -al$
A method that can follow, unsure whether or not this is the most efficient :
Next substitute all of our expressions into the integral in terms of x, and differentiate with respect to the parameter a and set it to zero to find the optimal parameter for a

The general trajectory is $y(x)=ax^2+bx-c$, with $a>0$, $c>0$. You are requesting that the parabola intersect the $x$ axis symmetrically at $x_1=L$ and $x_2=-L$. This condition is met if and only if $b=0$. In that case, the intersecting points are $x_1=\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}}$ and $x_2=-\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}}$. In other words, $c=L^2a$. The trajectory is then $y(x)=a(x^2-L^2)$.
Since there is no friction, the total energy is conserved. At the beginning, the particle has kinetic energy $T_0=\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$. At a generic point of the trajectory, it has kinetic energy $T_{f}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and gravitational potential energy $U=mgy(x)$. Equating both expressions give the norm of the velocity vector:
$$v=||\vec{v}||=\sqrt{v_0^2-2ga(x^2-L^2)}. $$
The time for going from $-L$ to $L$ is then
$$ \Delta t = \int dt=\int \frac{ds}{v}=\int_{-L}^{+L} \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{v}\, dx=\int_{-L}^{+L}\frac{\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}{v}\, dx=\int_{-L}^{+L}\sqrt{\frac{1+4a^2x^2}{v_0^2-2ga(x^2-L^2)}}\, dx.$$
Doing this with Mathematica gives
$$\Delta t=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{8 a^2 L^2+2}{v_0^2}} \sqrt{\frac{v_0^2}{2 a g L^2+v_0^2}} E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} L \sqrt{\frac{a g}{2 a g
   L^2+v_0^2}}\right)|-\frac{2 a \left(2 a g L^2+v_0^2\right)}{g}\right)}{\sqrt{4 a^2 L^2+1} \sqrt{\frac{a g}{2 a g L^2+v_0^2}}},$$
where $E(\phi|k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. Now, in principle we just have to differentiate the above expression with respect to $a$ and set the derivative to zero. However, it is impossible to get an exact expression and we can only try to find the minimum numerically. One can do this in Mathematica with $\texttt{FindMinimum}$. For example, if $v_0=1\,m\cdot s^{-1}$, $L=1\,m$, $g=9.8\,m\cdot s^{-2}$, then the optimal value of $a$ is $a\approx 0.647\,m^{-1}$ and $\Delta t \approx 0.943\,s$. As comparison, the time taken moving along a straight line ($a=0$) with the same numerical data is $\Delta t = 2\, s$.

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
$\def \p {\dot}$
$\def \pp {\ddot}$
with  the position vector$~\b R~$ to the mass
\begin{align*}
 &\b R=\begin{bmatrix}
         x \\
         y \\
       \end{bmatrix}=
       \begin{bmatrix}
         x \\
         y(x) \\
       \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{the  energy $~E~$ is }\\
       &E=\frac{m}{2}\,(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)+m\,g\,y(x)=
       \frac m2\,{{\p x}}^{2}+\frac m2\, \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)
 \right) ^{2}{{\p x}}^{2}+m\,g\,y \left( x \right)
\end{align*}
the energy $~E~$ is conserved thus$~ E=\rm constant=E_0$ where
\begin{align*} 
 &E_0=E(t=0)=E\left(\dot{x}=v_0~,x=L\right)=
 \frac m2\,{{v_0}}^{2}+\frac m2\, \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)
 \right) ^{2}\bigg|_{x=L}\,{{v_0}}^{2}+m\,g\,y \left( L \right)
\end{align*}
solving $~E=E_0~$ for $~\dot{x}~$
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{2\,{\frac {E_0-mgy \left( x \right) }{m \left( 1+ \left( {\frac
{d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }}
}\quad\text{or}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&t=\int_{L}^{-L}\left(\sqrt{2\,{\frac {E_0-mgy \left( x \right) }{m \left( 1+ \left( {\frac
{d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }}
}\right)^{-1}\,dx\tag 1
\end{align*}
your case is
\begin{align*}
 &y(x)=a\,x^2+b\,x+c\quad\text{with}~y(L)=0~,y(-L)=0~y(0)=-h\quad\Rightarrow\\
 &y(x)=\left( {\frac {{x}^{2}}{{L}^{2}}}-1 \right) h\\
 &
E_0=\frac{m}{2}\,v_0^2
\end{align*}
and equation (1)
\begin{align*}
&t=\int_{L}^{-L}\underbrace{\left({\frac {1+4\,{h}^{2}{x}^{2}}{\sqrt {{v_{{0}}}^{2}-2\, g\, h{x}^{2}+2\, g h}}}
\right)}_{f(x~,h)}\,dx\tag 2
\end{align*}
for which $~h~$ we obtain  the minimum time $~t~$? , with equation (2)
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{dt}{dh}=\int_{L}^{-L}\left(\frac{\partial f(x,h)}{\partial h}\right)\,dx=0\tag 3
\end{align*}
for a given $~\left(\frac{\partial f(x,h)}{\partial h}\right)~$ we can only solve  equation (3) for $~h_{\rm min}~$ numerically
Example
$~L=1~,v_0=1~,g=9.81~\Rightarrow h_{\rm min}=0.784$

the mass moves on the red trajectory the fastest
